# Kill WebSocket client connection non-gracefully

Tags: node.js

I read this: [How can I kill a Websocket connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268419/how-can-i-kill-a-websocket-connection) but it didn't really answer anything.

I'm writing a few test cases and one scenario is that the network will go down. I'm currently using the library: https://github.com/websockets/ws

Tests will be run in a Node.js environment but would be nice to know how to do this also in the browser.

I tried getting a hold of the socket object and calling destroy but that library would let grab the socket object.

Does anyone know a simple way to achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

`ws.terminate()` may be the answer you are looking for